# Application closes immediately after launch on one PC, but works fine on another

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've developed a Automation Project using *Selenium*, *Java* and *Netbeans*. Now, I must deliver it to my client. I've used the option "Clean and Build" on *Netbeans* for building the *jar*

When I launch that jar file on my laptop:\

1. Opens *JFrame* form.
2. Where I enter few fields and press Start ! button
3. It opens Chrome Browser using (chromedriver) and browse sites and save result in excel file

Although when I've tried it on another laptop (for testing purpose before sending it to client)

1. Opens *JFrame* form.
2. Where I enter few fields and press Start ! button
3. It opens Chrome Browser using (chromedriver) but immediately closes itself within second.

ERROR : https://ibb.co/k1NH7Bd

Is this information enough to solve my problem or I must provide more information as well. Looking Forward to hear from you guys.

Comment: Since the app works on one machine and not the other, it's not likely a code issue, but rather configuration.  It's best to debug it on the laptop to see if maybe Excel is involved too.

Comment: could be a difference in chrome version.  For convenience, I would try/catch exceptions and show a Prompt frame that displays the exception.  (This way the client can also tell you what error(s) they are seeing, and you won't have to run debugger on other machines.)

Comment: okay let me try this , thanks for suggestions guys

Comment: btw  both have same version of chromedriver @pcalkins

Comment: I have added error that i am getting after try catch. please check it out

Comment: it's the version of Chrome browser that is different.  I would also update to chromedriver v75... that'll work with Chrome browser version 75 and version 76.  (and seems more stable than chromedriver v76) Then go to Help>About in each Chrome browser to update them.

Comment: Thank you so much @pcalkins it works .